# Reformat Dataframe With Unique Row Values as Columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe formatted as follows:

```
Order#     Product
1          Milk
1          Water
2          OJ
3          Soda
3          Lemonade
```

I want to reformat this so that there is 1 row per order, each product as a column, and a binary to indicate whether that order contained the product in the column:

```
Order#     Lemonade     Milk     OJ     Soda     Water
1          0            1        0      0        1
2          0            0        1      0        0
3          1            0        0      1        0
```

I believe reshape2 or tidyverse are packages I could use, but I'm not sure. Any help on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just do `table(df1)`  If there are duplicates in 'Product', then `+(table(df1) > 0)`

Comment: The true dataframe has 130,000+ orders and 153 unique products. table(df1) gives me an error: "attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements"

Comment: Okay, can you do `library(data.table);dcast(setDT(df1), Order# ~ Product)` on a fresh R session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` as it would be more efficient and would work for bigger datasets

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Order ~ Product, length)
#    Order Lemonade Milk OJ Soda Water
#1:     1        0    1  0    0     1
#2:     2        0    0  1    0     0
#3:     3        1    0  0    1     0
```

Also, in case there are duplicates, change the `length` with a logical expression

```
dcast(setDT(df1), Order ~ Product, function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0))
```

---

For smaller datasets, the `table` from `base R` is also good

```
+(table(df1) > 0)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Order = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Product = c("Milk", 
 "Water", "OJ", "Soda", "Lemonade")), class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$v<-1
tidyr::spread(df,Product,v,fill=0)

  Order Lemonade Milk OJ Soda Water
1     1        0    1  0    0     1
2     2        0    0  1    0     0
3     3        1    0  0    1     0
```